# Windows change system volume programmatically with Java or CMD

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, system, volume

Is there any way to change the system volume on Windows with Java or CMD programmatically?

I've found some command lines for Linux and Mac, but so far nothing for stupid Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at a form post on oracles website https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2390172 you can see it is not possible from inside java using native libraries.

Quote from the oracle post: *"Because Java is cross-platform, it cannot do platform-specific stuff like changing the volume or whatever you want to do to control the OS. You need to use the operating system's unique API layer to do it."*

For command line I found this utility that seems to have what you are looking for http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

If you don't want to rely on 3rd party executables you could either make your own exe or make a dll and look into using JNI.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there could be a class, which internally handles the stuff and uses the specific / unique API layer, like the `Robot` class. The library looks pretty good.